# Find min value between 2 sets of vectors (fastest way)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that is the start and end times for a series of vectors.  So we have a bunch of x vectors and y vectors and I want to compare the minimum distance between the 2 vectors.  If two vectors have any overlapping parts then the min distance is 0 (in this application you can't have a negative distance).

Here's what the dataframe looks like (below is an easy way to grab it):

```
  x.start x.end y.start y.end
1       3     6       7     8
2      10    14      19    22
3      19    25      45    45
4      33    33      66    68
5     100   101      90   101
6     130   150     134   153
```

So I want to go row by row on the x vectors and for each x vector compare it to all y vectors and find the minimum distance between the two.

Below I accomplish this with a nested `for` loop but I need to repeat this many times with more vectors so speed counts.  This is slow.  What is the most efficient way to accomplish this task?

**Desired output:**

```
## > out
## [1]  1  2  0 11  0  0
```

I'd prefer to keep this in base R but if you have a faster way that is OS independent I'm open.

**The data:**

```
dat <- data.frame(
    x.start = c(3, 10, 19, 33, 100, 130),
    x.end = c(6, 14, 25, 33, 101, 150), 
    y.start = c(7, 19, 45, 66, 90, 134),
    y.end = c(8, 22, 45, 68, 101, 153)
)
```

Note that looking at my answer below may provide better understanding of the task.  I'll benchmark the results after a few competitors have risen.

Here is the desired output as a dataframe for easier comparison and understanding:

```
  min_dist x.start x.end y.start y.end
1        1       3     6       7     8
2        2      10    14      19    22
3        0      19    25      45    45
4       11      33    33      66    68
5        0     100   101      90   101
6        0     130   150     134   153
```

**A visualization of the 2 sets of vectors:**

[image]

So each of the red segments I'd like to know the minimum distance to the closest y vector (blue segments); though I see the x vector 33:33 and the y vector 45:45 don't show up but I think this gives a visual depiction of the problem.

***Benchmarking Results: Running Tally***

```
Unit: microseconds
                 expr      min       lq   median       uq        max neval
         GEEKTRADER() 5386.186 5553.659 5603.341 5678.214  68297.171  5000
            TRINKER() 1421.887 1480.198 1496.992 1517.985  63619.596  5000
       RICARDO_OPT1() 4748.483 4892.631 4974.968 5110.952 156400.446  5000
       RICARDO_OPT2() 7387.463 7583.859 7694.418 7845.564  70200.949  5000
          FOTNELTON()  437.576  462.767  473.963  486.091   6109.724  5000
     FOTNELTON_EDIT()  356.871  379.730  390.460  402.122   3576.174  5000
 RICARDO_SIMPLE_ANS()  801.444  842.496  855.091  870.952   3923.715  5000
             ALEXIS()  343.343  385.328  397.923  408.652   4169.093  5000
```

Comment: What do you mean "minimum distance between 2 vectors"?

Comment: @HongOoi The way I understand this is that each "vector" is an interval on the number line. You are trying to find the closest y-interval for each x-interval. So, for example, the first x-interval is (3,6) so the closest y-interval is (7,8). The "distance" is however far to get from the x-interval to the y-interval... which is 1 in the example.

Comment: @roliu that sounds accurate.  thanks for helping to clarify.

Comment: @Hing I added a picture representation so that may help.  I apologize for my lack of math terminology that may make my question more understandable.

Comment: @Tyler, do you have a larger dataset to test against that can be posted?

Comment: @Ricardo the dataset isn't much larger.  Maybe 70 rows.  What is larger is the number of vectors.  That's where the job gets slowed down.  So instead of x and y we have a-z vectors and we need to compare x to y as well as y to x because the distances will not be the same.  If it helps I can post more vectors as perhaps I've tried to narrow the problem too much.

Comment: aw man... that's a totally different problem ;)    But it looks like you're going to be in polynomial time, no matter what.  Simply by the nature of the problem.

Comment: Please note that I've edited my answer because `overlap` can in fact be computed in a much simpler fashion than what I did in the first attempt.

Comment: @TylerRinker are the data sorted in ascending order by default?

Comment: @SimonO1011 yes they are sorted in this order by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest and possibly fastest way to do it is as follows:

```
apply(dat, 1, function(d) {
  overlap <- (dat$y.end >= d[1] & dat$y.end <= d[2]) |
             (dat$y.start >= d[1] & dat$y.start <= d[2])
  if (any(overlap)) 0
  else min(abs(c(d[1] - dat$y.end[!overlap], dat$y.start[!overlap] - d[2])))
})
```

**EDIT:** `overlap` can be much simpler:

```
apply(dat, 1, function(d) {
  overlap <- dat$y.end >= d[1] & dat$y.start <= d[2]
  if (any(overlap)) 0
  else min(abs(c(d[1] - dat$y.end[!overlap], dat$y.start[!overlap] - d[2])))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is fastest. But here is one way to do it.

```
apply(dat[,1:2], MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) {
  min(apply(dat[,3:4], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(y){
    X <- c(t(x))
    Y <- c(t(y))
    #Check if the two line segments overlap else find minimum distance between the 2 edges of each line segments
    if (diff(range(c(X,Y))) <=  diff(X) + diff(Y)){
      return(0)
    } else {
      return(min(abs(outer(Y, X, "-"))))
    }
  }))
})
## [1]  1  2  0 11  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  I benchmarked the two solutions thus far.  Maybe this will spark others with a quicker solution.

Answer (score 1):

Two options below.  Both using by.  The less succinct option (#2), I believe will be faster.  I would be interested in seeing benchmarks.

Also, note the comment below the `by=` statements. From your sample data, it appears that each `x.start` value has a unique `x.end` value.  If that is the case, no need to include `x.end` in the `by` statement.  Otherwise, please correct that part.

```
  library(data.table)
  DT <- data.table(dummykey = "A", dat, key="dummykey")
  A <- DT[ , !c("y.start", "y.end"), with=FALSE][DT[, !c("x.start", "x.end"), with=FALSE], allow.cartesian=TRUE]
```

---

### OPTION 1

```
  A[, max(0, min(ifelse(x.start > y.start, x.start-y.end, y.start-x.end))), by=x.start]
                                                 # or by=list(x.start, y.end)
```

---

### OPTION 2

```
  A[, xstartGTystart := x.start > y.start]
  A[(xstartGTystart), candidates := x.start - y.end]
  A[!(xstartGTystart), candidates := y.start-x.end]

  A[, list(minDisance=max(0, min(candidates))), by=x.start]
                             # or by=list(x.start, y.end)
```

---

Comment: thank you for your multiple solutions.  Not the fastest but still a learning experience for everyone. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much simpler solution (relative to my previous answer), based on the fact that the data is long and not wide:

```
current <- c("x.start", "x.end")
comparedto <- c("y.start", "y.end")

apply(dat[, current], 1, function(r) {
  max(0, min(ifelse(r[[1]] > dat[, comparedto[[1]]], r[[1]]-dat[, comparedto[[2]]], dat[, comparedto[[1]]]-r[[2]])))
})
# [1]  1  2  0 11  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by all the above (and hoping I've not misunderstood OP):

```
alexis3 <- function()
{                   
 fun <- function(x1, x2, yvec1 = dat$y.start, yvec2 = dat$y.end) 
 { 
  if(any(c(yvec1, yvec2) %in% seq(x1, x2))) return(0)
  else min(abs(outer(c(x1, x2), c(yvec1, yvec2), `-`))) 
 } 

 mapply(fun, x1 = dat$x.start, x2 = dat$x.end)
}

#> alexis3()
#[1]  1  2  0 11  0  0
```

Comment: Well done.  fotNelton's edit solution was just slightly faster on multiple replications.

Answer (score 0):

A nested for loop answer:

```
## Convert start and end times to two lists of vectors
xvects <- mapply(":", dat[, 1], dat[, 2])
yvects <- mapply(":", dat[, 3], dat[, 4])

## Function to take vector x[i] and compare to all vector y    
FUN <- function(a, b) {
    vals <- abs(outer(a, b, "-"))
    if ((sum(vals) == 0) > 0) {
        return(0)
    }
    min(vals)
}

## Pre alot
out <- rep(NA, nrow(dat))

## Nested for loop
for (i in seq_along(xvects)) {

    outj <- rep(NA, nrow(dat))

    for (j in seq_along(yvects)) {

        outj[j] <- FUN(xvects[[i]], yvects[[j]])
    }

    out[i] <- min(outj)

}
```